# Include a divider between menu item groups. JavaFX

Tags: menu, javafx, java-8

How to insert a divider between groups of a menu items. For example:

Group 1:
Save, 
Save As

Group 2 
Open
Import

My hack is adding a disabled menu item in the middle, with a string value of "---------". So my current menu is something like this

"Save"

"Save As"

"--------"

"Open"

"Import"

Is there a more proper, elegant, way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the JavaFX [SeparatorMenuItem](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/SeparatorMenuItem.html).